# Get user value from Overwrite Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba

I incorporated some code I found on SO (specifically, the `Dir()` part on line 8). Once the 'Do you want to overwrite the file` part shows how do I get the value the user pressed (yes, no, or cancel) to apply further logic? Here is my code:

```
Sub SaveFile(fName As String)

cancelSave = False
Retry:
saveAsFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fName, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
On Error Resume Next
If saveAsFileName <> False Then
    If Not Dir(saveAsFileName) <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=saveAsFileName
    Else
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        -----HERE, I want to find out if the user pressed yes, no, or cancel.-----
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=saveAsFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
        End If
    End If
Else
    cancelSave = True
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solves it:

```
Sub SaveFile(fName As String)

cancelSave = False
Retry:
saveAsFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fName, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If saveAsFileName <> False Then
    If Not Dir(saveAsFileName) <> vbNullString Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=saveAsFileName
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=saveAsFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            GoTo Retry
        Else
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
Else
    cancelSave = True
End If

End Sub
```